# Getting process memory in .NET Core app

Tags: linux, process, .net-core, console-application

Memory usage information in .Net core console app running on windows is available from Process class like here:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().PeakWorkingSet64
```

The same line on Linux (default AWS Linux image) returns 0. Other memory usage fields also have default values on Linux.

What would be the right way to get memory usage information in my .net core app? Should I use something else or configure my app differently to get that information?

Comment: Looks like this is not supported on Linux: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26669#issuecomment-361742971. You can get current process information, but not historical ones, it appears.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. You can add your comment as an answer. Currently there is no PeakXXXX stats on non-windows implementations.